# Do content and :after work only on <labels>, not <input>?

Tags: css

I have a label and an input element:

```
<label class="required" for="email">Email</label>
<input type="text" id="email" name="email">
```

I've set the `.required` class on the label to append a '*' to it with CSS like this:

```
required:after {
    content:" *";
}
```

But some fields have no preceding label, so I want to append the '*' just before the input element whether it has a label or not. I've tried setting the `.required` class on `<input>` elements, but it's not working. So is the content trick possible on `<label>`, but not not `<input>`? Can I get it to somehow work with `<input>`?

Comment: Maybe just a simple `.` before the required class? You will get `.required:after`

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that the values specified in the `content` property, combined with the `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements, [apply](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#before-after-content) before or after the element's content, not the element itself.

Basically, that would map to `<input type="text" id="email" name="email"> *</input>`, which is why your not seeing what you'd expect.

I don't know what your limitations are or how much elbowroom you have, but the semantically correct approach would be to place a `<span>*</span>` before/after the input element.

Answer (score 1):

**FROM:** `<label class="required">Nombre</label>`

**TO:** `<label class="required">Nombre *</label>`

You could try this:

```css
form label.required:after {
    content: " *";
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<label class="required" for="email">Name</label>
<input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter Name">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add input or textarea style to a  wrapper and then override the default textarea or input style without border and background. Then, as said by Filip, you can add the :after selector with content property to the  element instead of the

I am using this approach to display a counter for the slides players in SlideOnline where the number of slides should be displayed in this format "X / Total" but X should be editable. You can see a live example here: http://slideonline.com/presentation/93 - Please look at the bottom right corner of the presentation player to see the counter with numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Try Using ID instead of Class

```css
#required:after {
  content:" *";
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<label id="required">Name</label>
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Name">
```